# Risk-Neutral CAPM

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, capm

In the paper [Measuring Equity Risk with Option-implied Correlations](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/rfs/25/10/10.1093/rfs/hhs087/3/hhs087.pdf?Expires=1488371384&Signature=GPnt2jzG4pgvOiYgLxlywSoe5l3MltwhRunMq7YxbXQecxm2zA0mSpcOdBW-YN81TYmqj3yo4-iwB2AAat2TBOUJ4SOcJFpC8ATS79nTQ6TejDzSzuEq7ap2Rg4bntsyCy~q2sNoqA0rwGE8tCXvo1tCduSuhDQ4GBgz~aMrilImTK5J0bbvhMlFmGPVgdwwp9lwr~UrpoXgaj7~8rqgJ18QQTzbGm0JdaHj6YkmLHTZVEuGXViQ6ds46oHmcGNuobItxuO5rCKOQCOPK31cj--3JoPA83fYJmOoynid4-qA1w0B~toFGpB3ulViX51JNESIfsvyvA3H27swaTT5vA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q), Buss and Vilkov replace the standard CAPM beta:

$$
\beta_{iM,t}^P=\frac{\sigma_{i,t}^P\sum_{j=1}^N w_j \sigma_{j,t}^P\rho_{ij,t}^P}{(\sigma_{M,t}^P)^2}
$$

With a risk-neutral beta:

$$
 \beta_{iM,t}^Q=\frac{\sigma_{i,t}^Q\sum_{j=1}^N w_j \sigma_{j,t}^Q\rho_{ij,t}^Q}{(\sigma_{M,t}^Q)^2}
$$

And show that the later works better in explaining the cross-section of returns. 
My question is whether there is any simple model that would deliver the second expression. There are several models that deliver the formula for beta under $P$, but I am not sure if there is any that could deliver the one under $Q$.

Comment: A good question for the authors...

Comment: What is $\tau$ in the second expression?

Comment: Typo. :)
Thanks. I have corrected it.

Comment: Is tu in you risk-neutral beta also typo?

Comment: Yes. It ended up there after correcting the first typo. Thanks again. It is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a good intuition about the meaning of implied correlation. Is this supposed to be correlation between some asset, $i$, and the index, $M$? Perhaps , maybe one way to think of risk-neutral beta is as the "correlated co-implied volatilities" of $M$ and $i$:

$Beta^Q_{M,i} = \rho^Q_{M,i} * \frac{\sigma^Q_{i}}{\sigma^Q_{M}}$

Getting the implied variances should be easy, a-la some model. Getting the implied correlations seems to a little more complex. The paper you reference defines implied correlation as:

$\rho_{ij_t}^Q = \rho_{ij,t}^P - a(1-rho_{i,j,t}^P)$

where $a$ appears to be some factor which is bounded between 0 and -1.

That's all I got. I wish I had a better intuition of what implied correlation was attempting to measure.

Comment: That I already know. It is just a parametric modelling under mild assumptions. Not at all what the question asks.

Comment: My first guess would be to derive implied correlations from traded index options. This, however, might be a bit problematic as you don't have enough single name options for all stocks in your implied CAPM to get the combination of all betas that you need. For a short paper on this check Nasir Afaf's works..